# How to custom sort a list?

Tags: python, sorting

Is there a way to make my own sort list?

like I want to sort this :

```
['planets', 'animals', 'humans']
['animals', 'planets', 'humans']
['humans', 'planets', 'animals']
```

to

```
['humans', 'animals', 'planets']
['humans', 'animals', 'planets']
['humans', 'animals', 'planets']
```

Comment: `kitarosort = lambda x: ['humans', 'animals', 'planets']`

Comment: What is the rule you're using to sort? It's clearly not alphabetic.... Robin's "solution" works when all you give us is the desired end result for three specific values, but if you want to extend it to a fourth value (or handle fewer values), there needs to be a *rule* to follow for the sorting, you haven't even hinted at one.

Comment: Without more details about the problem we won;t be able to help much but you can implement custom value generting functions to compare in `sorted`

Comment: I need to sort specific value not in alphabet but according to the value itself

Comment: And what's the "value" of of `"humans"` compared to `"animals"` for example? That's the point we're trying to get to

Comment: What does "the value itself" mean?  A string is a sequence of characters; that *is* "the value itself".  Which means when it's sorted, it's according to lexicographic order of the characters.

Comment: the value of human is 1 and animals is 2 and so on

Comment: What do you mean "and so on"?  What's the value of `"tree"`?

Comment: no its multiple list in one list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had to do something similar. Place each item into a list with the preferred order:

```
ordering_list = ['humans', 'planets', 'animals']
```

Translate this list into a dict of item versus priority

```
ordering_dict = {item: i for i, item in enumerate(ordering_list)}
```

Define a method to use as the sort key. For unknown values we can choose `len(ordering_dict)` to place these items at the back. You could also use any arbitrary value depending on your needs.

```
def ordering_key(item):
    return ordering_dict.get(item, len(ordering_dict))
```

Now sorting is easy:

```
import pprint


unsorted_data = [
    ['planets', 'animals', 'humans'],
    ['animals', 'planets', 'humans'],
    ['humans', 'planets', 'animals'],
    ['foo', 'planets', 'animals', 'humans'],
]

sorted_data = [
    sorted(data, key=ordering_key) for data in unsorted_data
]
pprint.pprint(sorted_data)
```

```
[['humans', 'planets', 'animals'],
 ['humans', 'planets', 'animals'],
 ['humans', 'planets', 'animals'],
 ['humans', 'planets', 'animals', 'foo']]
```

Comment: Nice! Needs a name, and I propose "flakesort". `;¬)`

Comment: @martineau Nah, I can't take credit. I think I first saw it in debian for their index files! https://github.com/guillemj/dpkg/blob/main/scripts/Dpkg/Control/FieldsCore.pm#L612

Answer (score 1):

Pass a `key` function to `sort` or `sorted` that maps the list elements into something that has the order you want.  Here's one possible solution for the example you gave:

```
>>> def kitaro(s):
...     return len(s), s
...
>>> sorted(['planets', 'animals', 'humans'], key=kitaro)
['humans', 'animals', 'planets']
>>> sorted(['animals', 'planets', 'humans'], key=kitaro)
['humans', 'animals', 'planets']
>>> sorted(['humans', 'planets', 'animals'], key=kitaro)
['humans', 'animals', 'planets']
```

Another possibility:

```
>>> def kitaro(s):
...     return {s: i for i, s in enumerate(
...         ['humans', 'animals', 'planets']
...     )}.get(s)
...
>>> sorted(['planets', 'animals', 'humans'], key=kitaro)
['humans', 'animals', 'planets']
```